# How could get data from volume attached to instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am new in openstack. I have a volume attached to an instance. The instance was running perfectly. I update the Ubuntu version 16.04 and afterwards restarting the instance, it is stuck in grub rescue mode. If i goto boot directory there i cannot see any files. I do not know how to solve this.

Furthermore, a volume is attached to this instance. I need the data in this volume. Is there any way to copy this data from volume into openstack machine. I can access the openstack machine by ssh. Openstack machine means where the ubuntu openstack is installed.

Thanking in advance for all the support